# select records from a table based on row comparison logic but using set operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I know the question sounds a bit weird but it's true here is the scenario

I have a table A [Id,PType,TNo] with no field unique. The following is the data set :

```
insert into test.dbo.test_tsac values 
(1, 'tf' ,  2 ),
(2, 'pg' ,  3 ),
(3, 'tf' ,  1 ),
(3, 'pg' ,  1 ),
(4, 'tf' ,  5 ),
(4, 'LL' ,  2 ),
(4, 'pg' ,  1 ),
(5, 'pg' ,  2 ),
(5, 'pg' ,  4 )
```

The requirement is as follows :

1.For an Id, if there is only one record keep it in the result set (example

```
(1, 'tf' ,  2 ),
(2, 'pg' ,  3 )
```

2.for an id if there is more than one record than

- if records have "tf" and "pg" as there pType then discard the "pg" records and keep the tf record (example data row 3 and 4  ) , however, if there is a case where for 1 id there are 3 or more records having multiple "tf"(anything other than PG) then we need to choose the one on the basis of Tno(ASCENDING) excluding the record with PG Example ( in these 3,

  (4, 'tf' ,  5 ),
  (4, 'LL' ,  2 ),
  (4, 'pg' ,  1 ),

we will choose 4,'LL',2 because 4,pg,1 is discarded and from remaining we need to sort ascending.

- if for an id there exist 2 records both with Ptype = PG then choose any one of them, probably ascending.

so the output of the above data set would be :

```
(1, 'tf' ,  2 ),
(2, 'pg' ,  3 ),
(3, 'tf' ,  1 ),
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
(4, 'LL' ,  2 ),
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
(5, 'pg' ,  2 ),
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

I really appreciate all the help from this awesome community, I am not expecting a fully executable query here. Any idea/approach/suggestion is of great help

Note that I will need to run this on a very big data set ( ~1M ) so I don't think using Cursor is advisable thus requesting something on the set-operations basis.But if cursor/loops are the last resort I'm in for it as well

I have tried with self-joins, separating tables on the basis of Ptype and then recompiling them... grouping also did not help.

Comment: Which of the three SQL dialects you tagged do you actually want to use?

Comment: The answer below worked, I would have gone for any one of them to solve it.  thanks for the help buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, with a conditional `ORDER BY`

```
declare @test table (Id int, PType char(2), TNo int)
insert into @test
values
(1, 'tf' ,  2 ),
(2, 'pg' ,  3 ),
(3, 'tf' ,  1 ),
(3, 'pg' ,  1 ),
(4, 'tf' ,  5 ),
(4, 'LL' ,  2 ),
(4, 'pg' ,  1 ),
(5, 'pg' ,  2 ),
(5, 'pg' ,  4 )

;with cte as(
    select *,
    RN = row_number() over (partition by Id order by case when PType = 'tf' then 1 end, PType, TNo)
    from @test)

select
    Id
    ,PType
    ,TNo
from 
    cte
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Bro you are awesome, i tried this for like full 2 hrs and you managed to do this in 30 sec what an amazing skill !! It worked though a very minor change last From should be changed to cte

Comment: HAHA, trust me @UlhasGupta I have had problems that have taken me days only for someone to answer immediately so I feel your pain. I fixed that error in an edit, but good catch.